# How to detect circular calls?

Tags: c++, deadlock

I've been looking for causes for deadlocks and strategies/tools to avoid and detect them.

Another potential cause for deadlocks is to have blocking functions calling other blocking functions in a circular way, so that eventually a call never returns.

Sometimes this is hard to discover, specially in very large projects.

So, are there any tools/libraries/techiques that allow to automate the detection of circular calls in a program?

**EDIT:**
I code mostly in C and C++ so, if possible, give any information about the topic that is applicable to those languages.

Nevertheless, it seems this topic is scarcely covered in SO, so answers for other languages are ok too. *although maybe those deserve a topic of its own if someone finds it relevant*

Thanks.

Comment: @sbi People read what we write and not what we mean. Fair enough. On the other hand, people often _stare_ at things without actually **seeing** them. I'm sorry if you looked at my question and thought that I simply wanted to learn C++ with it (there are much better resources than SO for that matter). It's updated now to avoid further ambiguities. If you'd like to share some piece of knowledge about the subject, and help me _expand_ mine even further, that'd be very nice of you. Otherwise, I appreciate your effort to show me that maybe I chose the wrong place to make the question.

Comment: Please explain whether you're looking for a static/compile-time tool or some sort of runtime protection/detection.

Answer (score 1):

Circular (or recursive) calls that try to acquire the same non-reentrant lock are one of the easiest to debug blocking scenarios: locking is deterministic, and can be easily checked. When the application locks, fire up the debugger and look at the stack trace to understand what locks are held and why.

As to general solutions for the problem of locking... you can look into some libraries that provide mutex ordering, and detect when you are trying to lock on a mutex out of order. This type of solutions might be complex to implement correctly, but once in place it ensures that you cannot enter a deadlock condition, as it forces all processes to obtain the locks in the same order (i.e. if process A holds lock La, and it tries to acquire lock Lb for which the ordering is correct, then it can either succeed or lock, but whichever process is holding lock Lb cannot try to lock La as the ordering constraint would not be met).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux there 2 Valgrind tools for detecting deadlocks and race conditions: [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html), [DRD](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html). They both complement each other and it's worth to check for thread errors by both of them.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to detect [deadlocks](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.lock-orders), use `--tool=helgrind`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to detect deadlocks (IMO) is to make a test program that calls all the functions in a random order in like 30 different threads 10000s of times.

If you get a deadlock you can use VS2010 "Parallel Stacks" window. Debug->Windows->Parallel Stacks
This window will show you all the stacks, so you can find the methods that are deadlocking.

A simple strategy I use to write thread-safe objects:
A thread safe object should be safe when its public methods are called, so you don't get deadlocks when it is used.

So, the idea is to just lock all the public methods that access the object's data.
Besides that you need to insure that within the class' code you never call a public method. If you need to use one of the public methods, then make that method private, and wrap the private method with a public method that locks and then calls it.

If you want better lock granularity you could just create objects for each part that has its own lock, and lock it like I suggested. Then use encapsulation to combine those classes to the one class.

Example:

```
class Blah {
  MyData data;
  Lock lock;
public:
  DataItem GetData(int index)
  { 
     ReadLock read(lock);
     return LocalGetData(index);
  }
  DataItem FindData(string key)
  {
     ReadLock read(lock);
     DataItem item;
     //find the item, can use LocalGetData() to get the item without deadlocking
     return item;

  }
  void PutData(DataItem item)
  {
    ReadLock write(lock); 
    //put item in database
  }

private:

  DataItem LocalGetData(int index)
  {
    return data[index];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find a tool that builds a call graph, and check the graph for cycles.

Otherwise, there are a number of strategies for detecting deadlocks or other circularities, but they all depend on having some sort of supporting infrastructure in place.

There are deadlock avoidance strategies, having to do with assigning lock priorities and ordering the locks according to priority.  These require code changes and enforcing the standards, though.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the use of a call graph. My intent was to find some way that could automate the process.

Comment: Are you looking for a static/compile-time check, or a runtime check?  How much modification of your current code base are you willing to tolerate?

Comment: A run-time check would be more useful because not all cases might be detected by source analysis. It happens I have threads calling functions that are executed in other threads and block the caller until the "call" is complete. This is kind of a message passing mechanism. The calls are not by direct function invocation, but by passing pointers to the handler to execute. I could add some instrumentation on those calls, which would be disabled on release builds. Is there any kind of instrumentation that can be used for that? Thanks.

Comment: It's complex, and difficult to get 100% coverage.  You need to somehow associate a lock state structure with a "conceptual thread" that includes your inter-tread synchronous calls.  This implies an extra parameter on the calls, unless you have some other structure in place that lets you unwind the call sequence.  When you wait on something, you also need to somehow identify the (conceptual) thread and resource you're waiting on.  The trickiest part is when you're waiting on a queue with multiple potential responders and responses -- just about impossible to crack that nut.